# RSH giving Connectin Refused error on RHEL

Tags: linux, rsh

I am trying to do `rsh` on one of my VM but getting connection refused error.
I have checked `/etc/hosts` and `/etc/resolv.conf` both have proper hostname, IP and domain.

Comment: What is the reason you want to use rsh? Ssh offers the same functionality but securely and is normally installed and running by default. If you need rsh for some reason please add the output of /sbin/service rsh status and ping between both machines to your answer.

Comment: as pointed out, rsh might not be activated (from memory in  `/etc/service.d` ? a file with remsh, you must have added a rpm `remote-service` ). I can't tell yet you were to do it, I'll have a look within twelve hours if question is still unsolved.

Answer (score 0):

Connection refused is the OS telling "I have no program to your connection to" that means that nothing is listening for your rsh commands.

If I'm not mistaken rsh connects to port 514 by default. So if you really must use rsh you need to check your target system for rshd

Please consider another service ...

Comment: It's actually the remote host saying "Your packets cannot be delivered to a listening socket" - a socket belongs to a process rather than to a program.  And it might be undeliverable for other reasons - some firewalls are configured to respond this way for blocked ports (and rsh is a port near the top of the list for firewalling out).